# 1 Gigabit Router Impact on LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, performance, ethernet

I am trying to increase the speed of my LAN, but I'd like to avoid over-spending on system components.

Specifically, I am setting up a NAS file storage system and I am experiencing extremely slow file upload and download speeds over WiFi. The current Upload speeds over WiFi <1mb/s. Current upload speeds over Ethernet are >10mb/s. 10mb/s is acceptable.

I see that one clear option to boost the <1mb/s speeds is to use an ethernet cable. This will boost my speeds immediately to >10mb/s. However, this will cost me close to $200 and the router I am using is a 100mbps.

I'm wondering if I just upgrade my router to a 1 gigabit router (assuming all other LAN components are 1 gigabit capable) will I be able to achieve those >10mb/s speeds over the WiFi connection?

I believe my ISP limits are currently at 54/54mbps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you routed everything to a gigbit ethernet switch, you could achieve gigabit internally without needing to upgrade the router itself.

You can get a basic 'known manufacturer' 8 port switch for about $£€ 20 these days & a cheap 802.11ac WiFi access point for about 30.

Sure, it's not going to be as good as uprating your entire structure, but it's a cheap alternative for inter-computer communication. You don't really need to upgrade the router itself until you have internet speeds to warrant it.

So, you route all internal devices to the switch, then one port from the switch goes to your existing router. You can extend this by connecting switch to switch around the house. This <strike>rat's-nest</strike> complex topography can get slightly overloaded if everything is trying to use the NAS all at once, but in practise you may never notice.

Note: This is not necessarily based on "CCIE best practices" but more on that I have a similar topology at home, which serves a houseful of devices very adequately. When I wired the house for ethernet 20 years ago, I didn't consider how much a home structure might need to expand, so I have single cables from floor to floor, with a switch to distribute around each floor.
It works well enough.
I even have wifi access points hanging off some of these, with no practical deterioration in overall speeds.

Comment: except the question had nothing to do with gigabit ethernet - it had to do with WIFI, and the poster likely doesn't know the difference.

Comment: My answer covers switch(es) & APs, peripherally. You could get both for half the price of a new router. Actually, checking 8-port switches, they're down to £20 now & cheap APs at 30..

Comment: 50 quid you can do both. Why waste money on a new router when the WAN doesn't need it?

Comment: I think this shows a third, better option that I was unaware of. In my current setup I am using the router as a switch, limiting the speeds to the router speed. From what I understand this solution adds a switch that enables 1000Mbps. This entirely eliminates any dependency on the router for connection.

Comment: The router's job, if you upgrade in this way rather than replace it becomes 1. to connect to the internet (your existing router is faster than your connection, so just fine) 2. to provide DHCP (IP addresses) to all your in-house devices. that leaves all other in-house tasks to run over the (cheap) new equipment without ever touching the router.

Comment: Thanks a ton. In the end I took your advice and hardwired a connection to the switch. All ethernet connected devices are hitting about 90MBs upload and 70MBs download. All of this ended up costing me less than $100. We definitely can update our router in the future to hit better WiFi upload and download speeds, it looks like 225Mbps  or about 28MBs will be the best we can do over WiFi. Thanks for clearly seeing through my novice question and helping me hit my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Summary - Getting a gigabit router will likely improve speeds, but its impossible to by how much. This, however has nothing to do with the LAN speed but to do with newer WIFI technology associated with new devices.

Your current router is likely to be using 802.11**g** on the 2.4 gig band.  Newer routers will likely be using 802.11**n** standard or better. You likely want to look for a router which uses 802.11**ac** or better with multiple antennas - the more the better, and to make use if the 5g band as much as possible as it has more spectrum available ans is less subject to interference.

Note that your ISP speed is irrelevant to lan traffic speeds (although I suspect that 54 megabit us not an ISL speed - as it coincides with the speed of 802.11ac)  Similarly, you should use ethernet where practical to reduce the amount of traffic on wifi giving more to thise devices that need it.

Also  when looking at the specs of your gear, note that a mb is a mega**bit** - about 1/8th of a megabyte. If you get a gigabit router you will see ethernet speeds if 1000mbit = about 125 megabytes.

Comment: I don't think the current router could be using 802.11ac if it provides such miserable speeds... and not on the 2.4 GHz band (11ac _is_ a "gigabit" standard, and it only supports 5 GHz).

Comment: @user1686 you are right.  Its to early in the morning for me and I got my standards confused.  I should have been talking about G vs AC.  54mbit = G

Comment: I have updated my answer to correct the wrong standards.